# Can I customize multiple table insertion from django admin

Tags: python, django

My models.py :

```
 class Employee_master(ModelWithoutAppName):
     rec_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     employee_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 class Employee_wage_details(ModelWithoutAppName):
     rec_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
     employee_rec =  models.ForeignKey(Employee_master)  
     basic =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)
```

My admin.py:

```
 admin.site.register(Employee_master)
```

Now from the admin section I easily can add or edit new records for

```
Employee_master
```

. Now from the same form of Employee_master in admin,I want to provide options to give inputs and insert records to my second model

```
Employee_wage_details
```

also at the same time. Is it possible? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sir that's possible.

On your `admin.py` file:

```
class Employee_wage_detailsInline:
    model = Employee_wage_details

class Employee_masterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [Employee_wage_detailsInline]

admin.site.register(Employee_master, Employee_masterAdmin)
```

I recommend `camelcase` for the model name like: `EmployeeWageDetails`