# How to insert data for multiple tables/models from the same page of django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am a Django newbie and working on admin section of my project. Below is my code for models.py.

```
class Shops(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField()
    other_details = models.CharField(max_length=100,null='true')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return (self.name)

class Shop_Type(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return (self.category)

class Shop_Category(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.ForeignKey(Shops)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Shop_Type)
```

Now I want to display option for inserting data in both "Shops" and "Shop_Category" tables from the single page of admin module as both of them are connected. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761996/can-i-customize-multiple-table-insertion-from-django-admin) question but failed to achieve what I want. Below is the code for admin.py I used:

```
class ShopCatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Shop_category

class ShopsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ShopCatAdmin]

admin.site.register(Shops, ShopsAdmin)
```

It is throwing some attribute error saying that - "'ShopCatAdmin' object has no attribute 'get_formset'"

It would be great if anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `ShopCatAdmin` as inheriting from an inline admin class, not the basic admin.

```
class ShopCatAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Shop_Category
```

(Note, Python style discourages underscores in class names; your models should be called ShopType and ShopCategory.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I tried this, but now it is saying that - 'module' object has no attribute 'InlineModelAdmin'. Do I need to include something over here?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `TabularInline`, updated.

Comment: Hey Daniel, one more help..!!
What if I want to add more tables in the same page ?
Do I need to add more class names separated by comma to inlines?
Something like this ?
    inlines = [ServicesAdmin, ..... ]

Comment: Yes, as long as the models have ForeignKeys to the base model.

Comment: Cool.. Thanks again Daniel..

And yaa I will take care about the class names going forward. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Sorry for bothering you again... But I am stuck with a complex problem in my project and was just wondering if you can help me out with this. Below is the link to my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/32966844/5031686